# in Aurelia - I need to inject data from array of numbers, but it injected in first and no more

Tags: aurelia

in Aurelia - I need to inject data from array of numbers, but it injected in first and no more.

see in example that the number of index 0 was injected well but when the number is change, the view is not update.

```
export class App {
  digits: number[]
  constructor() {
    this.digits = [1, 2, 3]
  }
  add() {
    this.digits[0]++
  }
}

<template>
  <p>digit: ${digits[0]}</p>
  <button click.trigger="add()">add</button>
</template>
```

Thank you all

Comment: What if you do **this.digits = [...this.digits];** right after the ++ command?

Comment: @Benny yes - this will work. because it will change the reference of the array - and cause a re-evaluation of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aurelia's strategy for observing arrays (in V1) doesnt work for index access.
as stated in the [docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#repeaters)

> Aurelia will not be able to observe changes to arrays using the
> array[index] = value syntax. To ensure that Aurelia can observe the
> changes on your array, make use of the Array methods:
> Array.prototype.push, Array.prototype.pop and Array.prototype.splice.

AU2 uses proxies to patch arrays, so binding using direct indexing should also work.

a better way to bind the view to the first element only of an array, will be to use a getter like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-payne-okrzk?file=/src/app.html

but note that this is also not recommended - because getters without `@computedFrom` are re-computed 5 times per second.